# .htaccess mod rewrite rules over ride intended rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess looks something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^grandopeningfreeflow      http://test.com/grandopeningfreeflow/  [L,R=301,QSA]
RewriteRule ^GrandOpeningFreeFlow      http://test.com/grandopeningfreeflow/  [L,R=301,QSA]


RewriteRule ^grandopening      http:://test.com/grandopening/  [L,R=301,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

When I use url http://first.com/grandopeningfreeflow , it redirects to test.com/grandopening instead of the test.com/grandopeningfreeflow. How do I make the two rules distinct?

Comment: Did you clear your cache or try with other browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^grandopeningfreeflow      http://test.com/grandopeningfreeflow/  [NC,L,R=301,QSA]
RewriteRule ^grandopening(/.*)?$      http://test.com/grandopening/  [NC,L,R=301,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I forgot to add the $ at the end :)